# Adobe: Edge Reflow how to use class instead of ID

Tags: css, adobe, adobe-edge, reflow

I am using Adobe Edge Reflow and have made several designs using the software.

One thing I have found is that in the CSS exported, each element has its own ID in the stylesheet.

In many cases there are elements that should use classes but I see no way of doing this in Reflow.

For one website I made I went through manually changing this, but as you can imaging it took quite a while.

If anyone knows any way of using classes in Reflow or a better way of managing the exported style sheet I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Edge products, at least as I understand it, are **design** tools..not website creation tools. They're intended to showcase designs before being handed off to a front-end developer who will translate the design iteration into properly formatted and structured code.

Comment: This how Adobe refer to it in their blurb "Start responsive designs faster and create high-fidelity **prototypes** through media query breakpoints, precise CSS layouts, grouping and more." (My emphasis)

Comment: With all due respect your answer does not help and is not valid.

There are features within Reflow that export code. The final export is in fact the css, html and assets.

I would appreciate it if someone who had used Edge Reflow could provide some insight.

Comment: "The final export is in fact the css, html and assets." Yes, it is but it's not a 'proper' website...with properly structured CSS as you have found. That's why it's a prototyping tool so that designs (not finished products) can be reviewed in a live environment and refined before being properly produced...but if you find a method...good luck.